# How to implement std::atomic ref counter?

Tags: c++

Let's say I have a `std::atomic<int>` variable `refCount`. And I want to have the following behavior:

```
if (refCount > 0) {
    ++refCount;
    // acquire the shared ownership
}
```

Of course this won't be working on multi threading conditions. I tried `fetch_sub` and `compare_exchange_strong` with no luck. But somehow std::shared_ptr succeeded doing it. I can't find out how they did it.

edit:
To be more specific, is the code below thread safe? If it is, How can I achieve the same thread safety using the above `refCount`.

```
#include<thread>
#include<memory>
using namespace std;

shared_ptr<int> sharedInt = make_shared<int>(1);

int main() {
    thread([]() {
        sharedInt = nullptr;
    }).detach();
    shared_ptr<int> cp = sharedInt;
}
```

Comment: What does not work? The `if`? Can you provide a working example demonstrating the error?

Comment: You need to show a little bit more about what you want to do with the `RefCount`. Indeed, this is not atomic and by the time you want to increment the counter, you could have a value of 0.

Comment: What's the logic behind this? I don't really see the meaning behind the "if greater than zero, then increment it". Does it have something to do with weak references?

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher My Problem is actually just the use case of `std::shared_ptr`, except that the "owners" don't really need the shared resource. They just need it to be alive and atomically destroyed when not needed. I don't want every owner take a `std::shared_ptr` with them.

Comment: Have you looked at how the standard does this?

Comment: The `shared_ptr` example is also not correct - [If multiple threads of execution access the same shared_ptr without synchronization and any of those accesses uses a non-const member function of shared_ptr then a data race will occur](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr). There are [atomic_load/atomic_store](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic) functions for concurrent access which use global mutexes internally.

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher I read the implementation of Visual studio. Looks like they take snapshot value of the counter and compare exchange, if failed, take a new snapshot and try again.

Comment: So you know what to do now ;)

Comment: @MatthieuBrucher Yeah ;)

Comment: @dewaffled I have no read/write operations on the value pointed by the share_ptr. So I guess no problem here.

Comment: @J.Doe In the example you do the assignment `sharedInt = nullptr;` and reading `shared_ptr<int> cp = sharedInt;` concurrently. This is not allowed. The correct code shoud be `std::atomic_store(&sharedInt, nullptr);` and concurrent `shared_ptr<int> cp = std::atomic_load(&sharedInt);`

Comment: @dewaffled You are right. Luckily my use case only need the refCount.